# Generate a random number with a seed between a range in ruby

Tags: ruby, random

I'm trying to get the banner image on my website to change once a day. I can see ruby has `srand` which will let me input a number for the date and return the same result every time it is called on the same day but this returns a very long number. I also saw rand lets me use a range like `rand(a..b)`.

Is there any way I can use srand with a range like I can with rand?

Comment: I'm not understanding your question.  Seeding with `srand` doesn't alter any of the ways in which you can call `rand`, so what's the problem?  It would help if you posted some actual code that illustrates what you think is an issue.

Comment: Can I combine srand and rand? I'm just looking for any way I can get a number between a range that changes daily.

Comment: Oh I see I was misunderstanding how srand works. I thought the return value was the random number generated by the seed. I see I can just call rand right before I call rand. Will this affect any other components in my rails app or can I do this safely?

Comment: `srand` determines the sequence of values created by calls to `rand`.  However, you can have multiple instances of class `Random` and seed them independently.

Comment: @Qwertie do you want a _random_ banner each day or just a _different_ one, e.g. by cycling though a list?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create a special/designated random number generator with any seed value you like:

```
special = Random.new 42 # create a new instance of Random seeded with 42
20.times { p special.rand(5..10) } # generate 20 random ints in range 5 to 10
```

Your `special` instance of `Random` is independent of [`kernel#rand`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Kernel.html#method-i-rand) unless you use `srand` to initialize it with the same seed value.

Comment: Ahh, thats perfect. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the date's [Julian day number](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-jd) as the seed:

```
require 'date'
Date.new(2017, 6, 1).jd #=> 2457906
Date.new(2017, 6, 2).jd #=> 2457907
Date.new(2017, 6, 3).jd #=> 2457908
```

This can then be used to generate a random daily index:

```
def number_of_banners
  10
end

def daily_banner_index(date = Date.today)
  Random.new(date.jd).rand(number_of_banners)
end

daily_banner_index
#=> 8
```

Or a random daily element from an array:

```
def banners
  %w(foo_banner bar_banner baz_banner)
end

def daily_banner(date = Date.today)
  banners.sample(random: Random.new(date.jd))
end

daily_banner
#=> "bar_banner"
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid breaking the random number generator for the rest of my application I went with

```
(Date.today.to_s.gsub('-','').to_i) % number_of_banners
```

While not exactly random it should work well enough for this case but I would be interested in better solutions.